# Download large files using SFTPor HTTPS

Tags: https, download, sftp, large-files

We have an application that generate many files with size of (2GB-10GB) we want to save these files in a server and allow specific customers to download them. The system will delete these files in 30 days (we have around 30 customers) .

From your experience which download method should we use SFTP or HTTPS and why?

And do you have any suggestion  how to grantee download Security?

Answer (score 1):

Depends on who downloads what.

If it is customers downloading the files, then make things as easy as possible: offer https and advise one or two download managers you have tested that allow to pickup a broken download again.

For internal use (backup and the like) I strongly suggest to use rsync via ssh. Much easier to use, since you can do incremental downloads, so only those files are downloaded that do not exist locally or have changed remotely. That means you can simply trigger synchronization on a daily bases and the files will comulate locally over time just as they are created remotely.

When using sftp or rsync via ssh: the ssh server should be configured *not* to accept passwords but only keys for authentication as this is more secure.